# JavaScript closure question with counter example

Tags: javascript, closures

Consider we have follow snippets:

```js
function Counter() {
  let count = 0
  
  function inc() {
    count += 1
  }
  
  function dec() {
    count -= 1
  }
  
  function getCount() {
    return count
  }
  
  return { getCount, inc, dec, count }
}

const counter = Counter()
counter.inc()
counter.inc()

console.log(counter.getCount()) // 2
console.log(counter.count) // 0
```

I am wondering why using function `getCount()` and directly return `count` variable shows different result. In my opinion they both reference the same `count` address, and after `inc()` calls its value should be altered accordingly.

Comment: No. One references the variable, the other references the property (that was never updated after having created it with the value `0`).

Comment: `return { count }` doesn’t return the “variable”, it returns ***the value*** that it was at the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`return { getCount, inc, dec, count }`:

1. Creates a new object
2. **Copies** the current values of those four variables onto properties with the same names
3. Returns that object

When you change the value of the `count` variable you do not change the value of the `count` property.

Comment: thx, i was considering this example: `let x = 0; y = x; x = 1;`. After changing `x`'s value to 1, the `y` still keeps 0 cause it stores the value of initial `x` stores all the time, rather than storing reference. I think that's the point to understand my confusion about my question

Answer (score 2):

The reason is because when you do `counter.count`, you are getting the count value off the of the new object you returned. That count is actually a copy of the value at the time it was created and will never get updated.

If instead, you create a class and use `this.count` instead, it'll always be updated.

```js
class Counter {
  constructor() {
    this.count = 0;
  }
  
  inc() {
    this.count += 1;
  }
  
  dec() {
    this.count -= 1;
  }
  
  getCount() {
    return this.count;
  }
}

const counter = new Counter();
counter.inc()
counter.inc()

console.log(counter.getCount()) // 2
console.log(counter.count) // 2
```

Or, if you want to do it the more old-school way:

```js
function Counter() {
  this.count = 0
  
  function inc() {
    count += 1
  }
  
  function dec() {
    count -= 1
  }
  
  function getCount() {
    return count
  }
  
  this.inc = inc;
  this.dec = dec;
  this.getCount = getCount;
  
  return this;
}

const counter = Counter()
counter.inc()
counter.inc()

console.log(counter.getCount()) // 2
console.log(counter.count) // 2
```

Or, you could make `count` and object with some value that would get updated:

```js
function Counter() {
  let count = { value: 0 }
  
  function inc() {
    count.value += 1
  }
  
  function dec() {
    count.value -= 1
  }
  
  function getCount() {
    return count.value
  }
  
  return { getCount, inc, dec, count }
}

const counter = Counter()
counter.inc()
counter.inc()

console.log(counter.getCount()) // 2
console.log(counter.count.value) // 2
```

Though that last one is a bit silly for this particular use-case.

Comment: You don't need to create a class (or even constructor) to create an object with methods that access `this.count`. The object literal returned by the factory function would be enough.

Comment: The object literal is enough if you are making use of `counter.getCount()`, yes. But if you want to access a count variable directly, there is no direct way. The pattern they used effectively makes `count` private, and the object literal returned has a separate, unchanging, copy of count. I gave them three of several possible ways to tweak it to make `count` be a live value.

Comment: Yes, but you neglected the fourth, simpler one :-) Your sentence "*If instead, you create a class and use `this.count` instead, it'll always be updated.*" should be only "*If instead you use `this.count`*", no mention of classes. Just do `{ count: 0, getCount() { return this.count; }, inc() { this.count++; }, dec() { this.count--; } }`.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly because `count` that you are returning from function is a copy of variable (*value* to be more accurate) and `getCount` is a function, which refers to reference of a `count` variable. More you can learn [here](https://javascript.info/object-copy).

Answer (score -3):

Because inside the `getCount()` you are reassigning the value of count i.e. `count = count + 1`